# foreach loop error reading from file

Tags: scala, file, foreach

I am trying to read lines from a text file into a foreach loop but I keep getting this error: `value getLines is not a member of org.xml.sax.InputSource`. Can someone explain what this error means, and how I can resolve it?

```
import scala.xml._
import collection.mutable.HashMap

val noDupFile="nodup_steam_out.txt"
Source.fromFile(noDupFile).getLines().par.foreach((res:String){
    //....
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import scala.xml._
import collection.mutable.HashMap

val noDupFile="nodup_steam_out.txt"
io.Source.fromFile(noDupFile).getLines().foreach(res => {
    //....
})
```

without the right import you are refering to `org.xml.sax.InputSource`

[io.Source.fromFile](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.io.Source$@fromFile(uri:java.net.URI)(implicitcodec:scala.io.Codec):scala.io.BufferedSource) returns a [io.BufferedSource](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.io.BufferedSource) and does not have the par method (defined on [Parallelizable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Parallelizable)).

You can write

```
import scala.xml._
import collection.mutable.HashMap

val noDupFile="nodup_steam_out.txt"
io.Source.fromFile(noDupFile).getLines().toStream.par.foreach(res => {
    //....
})
```

Comment: when I use your code and try to replace the `...` with `println(res)` nothing happens on screen, then the program exits without an error. Did I do something else wrong? (Yes the file exists, and it does have contents)

Comment: It should output something. Did you removed the comment also ?

Comment: I had a scope error in another part of my code, so the contents of the loop were never running.....fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to use the scala.xml library to iterate over you txt file. If you import scala.io._ instead, you should be able to do something like:

```
import scala.io._

val noDupFile="nodup_steam_out.txt"
Source.fromFile(noDupFile).getLines().foreach{ res =>
    //....
}
```

Comment: That solved part of my problem, but now I am getting an error on the `par.foreach`. How can I fix this `value par is not a member of Iterator[String]`